# WCF Web socket client also need to run on windows 8

Tags: wcf, websocket

I am new to WCF web socket and I am trying to implement duplex service using web socket. I have implemented the wcf web socket service using the following example and it works fine.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh977020.aspx

I know the minimum requirement for WCF service for web socket is windows 8 and .net framework 4.5. So I have hosted my service on windows server 2012 server machine. 
Then I have written WCF web socket client to access the service and my client is windows 
form applications runs on windows 7. I got the following error.

> “This platform does not support client side WebSockets natively.
>   Support for client side WebSockets can be enabled on this platform by
>   providing an implementation of
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientWebSocketFactory.”

Does web service client also need to have windows 8? If it needs are there any third party libraries to access WCF web socket service.

Really appreciate your reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need win8 or 2012server to be able to use the Microsoft WebSocket namespace in your WCF. You could also take a look at SignalR that will fallback to other techniques when WebSockets is not available.

You can also use XSockets.NET that will run websockets on .NET 4 (so there is no need for win8 or 2012server).

You also have SuperWebSocket and Fleck as options of .NET 4.

Edit: Added sample with WebSockets from  WCF .NET 4 here https://github.com/XSockets/XVA/tree/master/XVA-07-02-BoostWCF/Any%20OS

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. The conclustion is to use web socket both client and server has to be on win8 or 2012 server.                                                                I looked in to your github sample. but it is web api rest service. in my case i am using WCF service with duplex communications. and it need to support session so that i dont think rest service support session. thanks

Comment: Hello. My solution will support sessions. It is just a client and will work from anywhere within .NET 4

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i am not sure how can i call wcf web service methods from those available libraries.

Comment: Sorry, after reading the link you provided I understand what you want to do. Both SignalR and XSockets have StockSticker examples. But those are called from JavaScript and you are using winforms? It can still be done though. Will provide a sample in a few hours

Comment: Yes that is what I expected. Different implementation of web socket. but seems perfect for my requirement. Thanks again

Comment: The github links are broken

Comment: Yes @Mark, I killed em all a while back. I can point you to a new example ... Give me a moment to create it. Is it WCF or StockTicker you would like to see? Or anything else?

Comment: I would like to see the WCF sample first.

Comment: @Mark - Here is a first sample (https://github.com/XSockets/XVA/tree/master/XVA-07-02-BoostWCF) , will be updated later today where you can use a client instead of teh controller directly. Basically that means that the WCF can be located anywhere.