# The best way to use WebSocket on windows 7 with .net 4.5 client

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wcf, websocket

I need to make full duplex connection between server and client. Currently I have .net 4.5 wpf client. My initial thoughts was about wcf service with netTcpBinding. But it seems to be working only on windows 8. And client app has to be launched on windows 8.

I but I'd like to support windows 7 at least. I saw alternative in SignalR, but it will use server-sent events and I'm not sure in it.

Is it better to make web client with js connection to service? According to http://caniuse.com/websockets chrome and firefox supports it for a long time. If so can I host wcf service with websockets and connect to him from js? I'm wondering why browser supports it and in same time wpf doesn't...

Also performance for connection is not last thing, it should real fast.

Comment: `it seems to be working only on windows 8` you start with a wrong assumption

Comment: @EZI I'd say that's an observation as opposed to an assumption and a perfectly valid assertion.

Comment: @EZI That's cool! I read a lot of similar topics and made such assumption. Why it's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your question, I do not believe that netTcpBinding is the best choice for this. If I where you I'd use this binding: binding [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.wsdualhttpbinding(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.wsdualhttpbinding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

That binding is SOAP so you're likely to get better compatibility and it is designed specifically for duplex connections.

As for SignalR and js connection to service I would say at this point you seem to have a working solution and changing the binding is probably a short solution; however, only you can really know for sure.

I don't think you need this; however, just in case here is an example of using duplex over wcf. (I used TcpNamedPipe in this example instead of WSDualHttpBinding; however, you only need to make minor changes to get the desired result)

https://github.com/Aelphaeis/MyWcfDuplexPipeExample

Comment: Yep, you might be right. I need to make something like auction. Clients can send their bids and asks and once some bid and ask  matched service has to send notification to both of them. Also connection should be secure.

Answer (score 1):

WebSockets are a technology for allowing bidirectional comms over a single TCP connection. It is intended to be used between browsers and webservers, but that doesn't mean you can't use it in other platforms.

There is a C# WebSocket client out there on GitHub (also on NuGet) that you could use to experiment with.

https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp

Comment: I made such conclusion regardless to this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17039071/wcf-web-socket-client-also-need-to-run-on-windows-8 Guys said client and server must be ran on windows 8 or windows server 2012. And in case with third parties they just emulates work of the websockets.

Comment: Other OS than windows is not interesting for me.

Comment: Third parties do not emulate the functionality, the provide it from scratch.